# SupportLibrary cause trouble with GravityCompat

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have an app where I must use Fragment ActionBar and also `GravityCompat` that is ony in support library.

I have changed all the import from non-support version

```
import android.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

To

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

to avoid the error "*is not applicable for the argument*" caused by collision between classes

However the app often crash at the start at the line

```
mDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
```

because in the `onCreate` doesn't find `GravityCompat`, but I have yet added(and checked as enabled in build path) all support libraries needed,

in fact if I try

```
try{
            mDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        }
        catch(RuntimeException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The apps works fine.

How could avoid this problem without mask the error in a naive-way?